# Search ranking in SP 2013

Tags: 2013, search, search-results

I am using Sharepoint search and able to retrieve all the items using search . Now I need to define a special ranking that ranks documents based on how many times a document is viewed ignoring the standard ranking in Search Results. How can this be done in Sharepoint 2013 ?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want to create a custom ranking model: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn169052.aspx

1. You essentially create a copy of an existing model that you export to XML from the SSA with PowerShell.
2. Edit the exported model to use the approach you want. The file is formatted like this:

> ```
> <rank_log version='15.0.0000.1000' id='[internal guid of ranking model used for calculation]' >
>     <query tree='[representation of user query used for ranking]'/>
>     <stage type='linear'>
>         [Details of rank calculation of the first ranking stage. One XML node for each rank feature.]
>         <stage_model>
>             [Definition of the first stage of the ranking model]
>         </stage_model>
>     </stage>
>     <stage type='neural_net' >
>         [Details of rank calculation of the second ranking stage. One XML node for each rank feature.]
>         <stage_model>
>             [Definition of the second stage of the ranking model]
>         </stage_model>
>     </stage>
> </rank_log>
> ```

1. Reimport your model again with PowerShell
2. Test, tweak, test

Answer (score 1):

The link should be http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/c166ecdd-7f93-4bbb-b543-2687992dd2bc.aspx

Also, the xml example provided by Matthew does not represent the xml of the ranking model itself, but the output of the rankdetail property for a specific document matching a specific Query.

Before starting creating a custom ranking model, you should make sure that you have installed the August 2013 CU, which came With a new ranking model with two linear stages.